# how to detach a click event handler which has a wdatepicker inside?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's an input element ready for picking date.

```
<input type="text" id="txtPickDate" />
```

This element had been attched with a `click` event handler:

```
$("#txtPickDate").on("click", function(){
    WdatePicker({ skin: 'whyGreen', dateFmt: 'MMdd',isShowClear:false,readOnly:true });
});
```

this event handler could pick the date as 'MMdd' format. But somehow I want it to be picked as 'yyyyMMdd'. I've tried this but it didn't work:

```
$("#txtPickDate").off("click").on("click", function(){
    WdatePicker({ skin: 'whyGreen', dateFmt: 'yyyyMMdd',isShowClear:false,readOnly:true });
});
```

I think it could have worked, but eventually the element `txtPickDate` seemed to be attched with **two** handlers! What would you suggest me to do it right?
Any help will be greatly appreciated.